# Vertical align property aligning element

Tags: html, css

The spec mentions that the vertical-display property (which only applies on inline and inline block elements ) aligns the element itself but not its content. A span, as i understand it is the element. In this fiddle everything works as expected but would need to be done in order to center the actual text "Beta" in the span?

https://jsfiddle.net/69uhamv5/

```
.b{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  height:120px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

<span class="b">Beta</span>
```

P.S: Im not looking for a quick solution, i am aware i can use line height or display table or a handful of other things. I am more intersted in figuring out exactly why it is that this doesnt work, or rather, why it is that it targets the span element but not the text inside and what would i need to to to target the text inside.

Comment: Quick solution is `line-height: 120px;`

Comment: `vertical-align:middle;` not working on `display: inline-block` best solution is above comment.

Comment: vertical-align property works for display: table-cell too.. btw., that property is related to the siblings of the element. if you want to alight the text., then why dont you align the span than going for the text?

Comment: thank you all but i forgot to mention im not so much looking for a workaround, rather, an explanation of  why it doesnt work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have somme solution:

**Variant 1** add line-height

```
.b{
  background-color:red;
  display: inline-block;
  height:120px;
  line-height: 7.5em;
}
```

try here: https://jsfiddle.net/69uhamv5/6/

**Variant 2** center with table

```
.b, span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.b {
  background-color:red;
  height:120px;
  }

body{
  display: table;
  height:300px;
  }
}
```

try here https://jsfiddle.net/69uhamv5/5/

Comment: variant 1 seems to work but would would one do if the height of the containing element wasnt static but a percentage? line-height doesnt utilize a percentage right? ( and even if it did i would assume it would refer to the width as percentages many times do )

Comment: Yes, line-height doesnt utilize a percentage. And center with line-height is a solution only for a static block and only for one line. Maybe, you want to say a flexible height not percentage. For flexible height Variant 2 must work great. Even with multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach :

```css
.b{

  background-color:red;
  height:120px;
   display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}

body{
  height:300px;
  
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span >Alpha</span><span class="b">Beta</span><span>Gamma</span>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: flex is a css3 property., so it may have compatibility issues on older browsers